# How to get views from 2nd XML activity into the current Java file

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I'm practically new to Android development and I'm facing a rather silly issue for the experienced of you.

I have a `PopupWindow` inside my `MainActivity` which loads from a second XML file like so:

```
public void showMapLevelsPopup(View view) {
    final PopupWindow mypopupWindow;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (inflater != null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_types, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.map_settings), false);
    }

    mypopupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mypopupWindow.setElevation((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 3, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    mypopupWindow.showAtLocation(mRelativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.END, 0, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, -150, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

And the `map_types` XML is configured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_gravity="top|end"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/map_settings">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MAP TYPE"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/map_options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_mlv_default"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/map_levels_default"
                android:text="Default"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_mlv_satellite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/map_levels_satellite"
                android:text="Satellite"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_mlv_terrain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/map_levels_terrain"
                android:text="Terrain"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MAP DETAILS"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_traffic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Traffic information"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see the context is configured to my `MainActivity` (`tools:context=".MainActivity"`). The issue is that I'm trying to get the `RadioButton`s when they change but my Java file completely ignores them.

I have this function inside `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity`:

```
    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();

    final View mapOpts = factory.inflate(R.layout.map_types, null);


    RadioGroup mapOptions = mapOpts.findViewById(R.id.map_options);
    mlvDefault = mapOpts.findViewById(R.id.radio_mlv_default);
    mlvSatellite = mapOpts.findViewById(R.id.radio_mlv_satellite);
    mlvTerrain = mapOpts.findViewById(R.id.radio_mlv_terrain);
    cbTraffic = mapOpts.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_traffic);

    if (mapOptions != null) {
        mapOptions.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.radio_mlv_default:
                        mlvDefault.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.map_levels_default_selected);
                        mlvDefault.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_mlv_satellite:
                        mlvSatellite.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.map_levels_satellite_selected);
                        mlvSatellite.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_mlv_terrain:
                        mlvTerrain.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.map_levels_terrain_selected);
                        mlvTerrain.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

but nothing seems to be working! I also tried setting the trigger with a `public void` outside the `onCreate()` method and through `android:onClick` in the XML but that didn't work as well (caused an exception). What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you edit post & share the MainActivity. I guess I got your issue.

Comment: First, just FYI, the `tools:context` attribute is only for the IDE, so it displays your layout correctly at design-time. It doesn't mean anything during runtime. Beyond that, layouts are just blueprints for `View`s. Every time you inflate one, it's a new instance that's completely separate from any other that might be inflated. The setup you do in `onCreate()` applies to only that instance. It won't apply to the instance you inflate in `showMapLevelsPopup()`. You need to move that setup to there, and set your listener on that.